# Replace multiples characters at same time in ruby

Tags: ruby

Are there a better way to wrote the same code below?
I am looking for a clean and minimal code.

```
val.gsub!('A', 'Q')
val.gsub!('B', 'W')
val.gsub!('C', 'E')
val.gsub!('D', 'R')
val.gsub!('E', 'T')
val.gsub!('F', 'Y')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`tr`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/String.html#method-i-tr), it's purpose-built for the problem you're describing:

```
> val = "ASDFGHJKL"
=> "ASDFGHJKL"
> val.tr("ABCDEF", "QWERTY")
=> "QSRYGHJKL"
```

Without using any other methods than the ones you already know about, you could build a key/value mapping, and then iterate over the pairs:

```
{ 'A' => 'Q', 'B' => 'W', 'C' => 'E' ...}.each { |x,y| val.gsub(x, y) }
```

Comment: Or `val.gsub(/./) { |c| h.key?(c) ? h[c] : c }`, where `h` is the hash you refer to but `tr` is, you say, purpose-built for this.

Comment: You could also hand `gsub` a Hash as the second argument: ["If the second argument is a Hash, and the matched text is one of its keys, the corresponding value is the replacement string"](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/String.html#method-i-gsub), you'd still have to build the appropriate pattern of course.

Comment: Good point, @muistooshort.  I forgot about that form of `gsub`.